# JSON Data not displaying in ng-grid in angular

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, ng-grid

I've got a controller that makes an HTTP Call to the database. It returns the data, verified by the $log command but does not display it in the grid. Here's the code..

Thanks in advance...

```
eventsApp.controller('TerrController',    
function TerrController($scope, territoryData) {
    $scope.territory = [];

    //$scope.gridOptions = {
    //    data: 'territory', columnDefs: [
    //        { field: 'TerritoryID', displayName: 'ID'},
    //        { field: 'TerritoryDescription', displayName: 'Description' },
    //        { field: 'RegionID', displayName: 'RegionID' }]
    //};

    territoryData.getTerritories().then(function (response) {
        var tmpData = angular.fromJson(response);
        $scope.territory = tmpData;
    });
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'territory', columnDefs: [
            { field: 'RegionID', displayName: 'RegionID', visible: true },
            { field: 'TerritoryDescription', displayName: 'Description', visible: true     },
            { field: 'TerritoryID', displayName: 'ID', visible: true }]
    };

});

eventsApp.factory('territoryData', function ($http, $q, $log) {
return {
    getTerritories: function () {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Home/GetTerritories' }).
        success(function (result, status, headers, config) {
            angular.forEach(result, function (c) {
                $log.log(c.TerritoryDescription);
            });

            deferred.resolve(result);

        }).
        error(function (result, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(status)
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

});

Comment: My initial thought is that the data is not available when the grid is first initialized.  The reason you see it getting printed in the log is because that is in the callback function from the http request.  Have you tried just putting static data into $scope.territory to see if it is displayed?  I would first determine whether this is a data binding issue or a service issue.

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved?